# Interpolate df column within each group

Tags: r

I have a data frame `df` and a sample vector `years` of the following kind:

```
> df <- data.frame(year  = rep(c(2000, 2025, 2030, 2050), 2),
                   type  = rep(c('a', 'b'), each = 4),
                   value = c(3, 9, 8, 6, 7, 5, 2, 10))
> years = seq(2010, 2050, 10)
    
> df
  year type value
1 2000    a     3
2 2025    a     9
3 2030    a     8
4 2050    a     6
5 2000    b     7
6 2025    b     5
7 2030    b     2
8 2050    b    10

> years
[1] 2010 2020 2030 2040 2050
```

Now I would like to interpolate `value` within each group of `type` to get the values for `years`. My expected result looks like this (where values for 2010, 2020 and 2040 are interpolated):

```
> result
   year type value
1  2010    a   5.4
2  2020    a   7.8
3  2030    a     8
4  2040    a     7
5  2050    a     6
6  2010    b   6.2
7  2020    b   5.4
8  2030    b     2
9  2040    b     6
10 2050    b    10
```

I have tried something like this but did not succeed as I am not allowed to change the length of the group. Any help is very much appreciated!

```
> result <- df %>%
      group_by(type) %>%
      mutate(year = years,
             value = approx(year, value, years)$y)

Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `year`.
x Input `year` can't be recycled to size 4.
i Input `year` is `years`.
i Input `year` must be size 4 or 1, not 5.
i The error occurred in group 1: type = "a".
```

Comment: Your input data was created with `sample`.   Please use `set.seed`

Comment: You are right, thank you. I changed it to a fixed input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `complete` to get all the sequence per 'type' and then apply `approx`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)   
df %>%
   complete(year = years, type) %>%
   group_by(type) %>%
   mutate(value = approx(year, value, year)$y) %>%
   ungroup %>% 
   arrange(type, year)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 14 x 3
#    year type  value
#   <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
# 1  2000 a       3  
# 2  2010 a       5.4
# 3  2020 a       7.8
# 4  2025 a       9  
# 5  2030 a       8  
# 6  2040 a       7  
# 7  2050 a       6  
# 8  2000 b       7  
# 9  2010 b       6.2
#10  2020 b       5.4
#11  2025 b       5  
#12  2030 b       2  
#13  2040 b       6  
#14  2050 b      10
```

Comment: @McCuys can you check the updated solution

Comment: perfect, that does the job. Thank you!

Comment: @McCuys sorry, earlier I was using wrong dataset and didn't had time to crosscheck the output